# Any specific event for clicking on the Button of the combobox

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, farpoint-spread

C# WinApps:
is there any separate event that can tell us user has clicked on the small drop button next to the combobox?

Suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, `ComboDropDown` event should work. As written in [docs](http://blogs.fpoint.com/FarPointSupportSite/Modules/Docs/SpreadWin5Help/FarPoint.Win.Spread~FarPoint.Win.Spread.FpSpread~ComboDropDown_EV.html):

> This event is raised by the
>   OnComboDropDown method when the user
>   clicks the drop-down arrow or presses
>   the Alt+down arrow keys in a combo box
>   cell ...

If it doesn't work for you, it seems like a bug.

Possible workaround:

Handle [`CellClick`](http://blogs.fpoint.com/FarPointSupportSite/Modules/Docs/SpreadWin5Help/FarPoint.Win.Spread~FarPoint.Win.Spread.FpSpread~CellClick_EV.html) event and check coordinates from [`GetCellRect()`](http://blogs.fpoint.com/FarPointSupportSite/Modules/Docs/SpreadWin5Help/FarPoint.Win.Spread~FarPoint.Win.Spread.FpSpread~GetCellRectangle.html).

Comment: ok, tried it: well I am using FarpointSpread sheet and using a comboBox cell type inside one of its cells... it does not have DropDown but it does have ComboDropDown event which I had tried it before... if I click on the editor area, it fires...if i click on the button it does not fire in my app...

Comment: @max There is no ComboDropDown or DropDown event. The only event I found is : DropDownClosed. There is no DropDownOpened event.

Answer (score 1):

Not that event exactly, but, how about the click event, then you can check out the mouse position and check if it's in the little button area, perhaps?

Comment: well how to check the position?